How to place my own code snippets on command line à la history?
I have hundreds of tested and tried commands and snipets saved in various text files. When I need to re-use one, I find and copy/paste to the command line. Though reliable this is a clumsy method. Compare this to the elegant way we can retrieve an old command from history file straight onto the command line and ready to edit and use. How can I emulate this feature and use my own collection of commands?
I have scripts to search (using fzf), find and append my own command(s) to history file. This works well. But it does clutter up the history file.
Here is my script:
find ~ -type f | fzf --preview-window=up:50% --header "ENTER:less; ^s:snip to history" --bind "enter:execute(less {})"  --bind "ctrl-s:execute(cat {} | fzf -m --preview-window=:hidden  >>~/.bash_history)"; history -n


Put them in named functions in a file and source that file?

Which shell do you use? Fo you want to use the shell's history file, or a separate one you manage independently? And what do you mean by "emulate"? Are you familiar with history expansion?

Can you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve exactly? For instance: "One I do this (type a command? use a shortcut?), I want that to happen"? What are the exact requirements?

I am using bash (interactive shell). Not looking for shortcuts or expansion. I want to pull out one of my own (often long and complicated commands), place it on the command line and edit it for re-use -- ideally in the same way that history works.

But that's the question, how exactly do you want to pull it out? How do you intend to search and choose the command you want to run? Again, show a concrete example.

What kind of edits do you typically make? You may want to define a parameterized function instead of digging through your command history all the time.

Just a note regarding your script: you can append entries to history directly without writing to files by using "history -s your_cmd"

The gist of my question:-- is there a way I can place a line of text (say the output of a script) on the command line? I do not want to copy/past.

It might be worth exploring xdotool to solve your problem.
According to the man page:

xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input
and mouse activity,move and resize windows, etc.

So what you could do is to define an alias that helps you find your favorite command and tells xdotool to place it on the command line. For example:
$ alias my_command='stty -echo &&  xdotool type "$(cat any_list | fzf)" ; stty echo'

This would allow you to pull any line of text from a file "any_list" and place it on the command line. If that text happens to be one of your old commands then you are ready to edit and execute it.
You may already have xdotool in your current setup. If not it is very easy to download and install it -- for example https://installati.one/install-xdotool-debian-12

$user9101329 thanks. Never heard of xdotool. Installed and tested. Works like charm.

A quick and dirty contraption for interactive Bash (my bash --version prints 5.2.15):

Put your desired (single-line) commands in ~/.commands.

Define the following helper function:
_get_command () {
   READLINE_LINE="$(<~/.commands fzf -1 --query="$READLINE_LINE")" &&
   READLINE_POINT="${#READLINE_LINE}"
}


Bind to a key (key sequence):
bind -x '"\C-x\C-r":_get_command'


Start using Ctrl+x, Ctrl+r.


Notes:

READLINE_POINT="${#READLINE_LINE}" should place the cursor at the very end. Bash 5 wants the length in characters and the above code works; but Bash 4 wants bytes. To handle non-ASCII text in Bash 4 use
READLINE_POINT="$(printf '%s' "$READLINE_LINE" | wc -c)"

(I learned from this answer).

For ~/.commands you can invent your own format that specifies or encodes the desired position of the cursor for each command. Improve the helper function to set READLINE_LINE and READLINE_POINT according to your format.
On the other hand ~/.commands that stores only literal commands is simple and works nicely with --query="$READLINE_LINE".

For multi-line commands you need fzf --read0 and null-terminated entries in ~/.commands. Maintaining this format will be harder than editing newline-terminated entries.



After I wrote the above, I decided I want this functionality. Here is my more complex solution (to put in ~/.bashrc):
export SNIPPETFILE

_del_snippet () {
   SNIPPETFILE="${SNIPPETFILE:-"$HOME/.snippets"}"
   printf '%s\0' "$1" | sort -zm -- "$SNIPPETFILE" - | uniq -zu >"$SNIPPETFILE"~ \
   && mv -- "$SNIPPETFILE"~ "$SNIPPETFILE"
   cat -- "$SNIPPETFILE"
}
export -f _del_snippet

_get_snippet () {
   SNIPPETFILE="${SNIPPETFILE:-"$HOME/.snippets"}"
   local line
   line="$(<"$SNIPPETFILE" fzf -1 --read0 --query="$READLINE_LINE" \
      --border top --border-label 'Enter to confirm, Ctrl+y to delete entry, Ctrl+c to abort' \
      --bind 'ctrl-y:reload-sync(exec bash -c "_del_snippet \"\$1\"" bash {})')" \
   && READLINE_LINE="$line" \
   && READLINE_POINT="${#READLINE_LINE}"
}
bind -x '"\C-x\C-r":_get_snippet'

_put_snippet () {
   [[ "$READLINE_LINE" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && return 0
   SNIPPETFILE="${SNIPPETFILE:-"$HOME/.snippets"}"
   if
      touch -- "$SNIPPETFILE" \
      && printf '%s\0' "$READLINE_LINE" | sort -zum -- "$SNIPPETFILE" - >"$SNIPPETFILE"~ \
      && mv -- "$SNIPPETFILE"~ "$SNIPPETFILE"
   then
      printf 'command stored in `%s'\''\n' "$SNIPPETFILE" >&2
   else
      printf 'storing in `%s'\'' failed\n' "$SNIPPETFILE" >&2
      return 1
   fi
}
bind -x '"\C-x\C-m":_put_snippet'

Usage:

Store the current command line with Ctrl+x, Ctrl+m.

Use Ctrl+x, Ctrl+r to choose from the list of stored commands. If there is exactly one match to what you have already typed, it will be brought to the command line. If there is more, you will be able to choose interactively.

When choosing interactively, Ctrl+y deletes the highlighted entry.


Notes:

Multi-line commands are supported, but to store them right you mustn't hit Enter (inside quotes or after \) that would make a secondary prompt appear. You need to bring a multi-line command from the history or make a command multi-line by pressing Ctrl+v, Ctrl+j, so no secondary prompt appears and you can still edit the whole command. Then Ctrl+x, Ctrl+m will be able to store the whole multi-line command.
Such lines will not look like multi-line commands when you interactively choose them, but they will be brought to the command line as multi-line.
This creates a nice side effect: you can store labelled commands. This one
# description (label) here
:
actual_command args

will look like this in the list:
# description (label) here : actual_command args

and yet it will work after being chosen.

The default file is $HOME/.snippets. You can use another pathname by setting and exporting the variable named SNIPPETFILE. The pathname with postpended tilde (e.g. $HOME/.snippets~) will also be used for maintenance.

Tested in Bash 5.2.15 with GNU sort and GNU uniq (non-portable options used).

There may still be bugs.



Thanks @Kamil Maciorowski for the code. I am already doing exactly this. Your selection goes to the terminal. I want the selection to land on the command line (just as in history). At the moment what I do is to append the selection to my history file (instead of the terminal). But would be nice not to have to interfere with history, which is what I am after.

@dhm "I want the selection to land on the command line" – I thought this is what my solution provides. Hit Ctrl+x, Ctrl+r, choose a command, Enter. What is your version of Bash?

I don't know about @dhm, but I too tried your code and he is right. The selection does land on terminal -- not the command line.

@user9101329 This information is not useful until someone tells me the version of Bash where my code does not work well.

$Kamil Maciorowski. Thanks for your update and attention. I have edited my post and added my current script. I use Ubuntu (bash 5.0.17) and Debian bookworm. The script works on both. The selections get added to the history file which is then conveniently useable.

in bash, shell-expand-line (keyboard shortcut M-C-e, usually ALT+CTRL+e) will "Expand the line as the shell does. This performs alias and history expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions".
So the easiest way to achieve what you want, is to assign the command you want to insert to the command line to some variable, write the name of the variable and then press this key sequence to expand to its content.
For instance:
$ COMMAND="echo hello world"

Now in the command line write the name of the variable, $COMMAND in this case, and press ALT+CTRL+e. $COMMAND will automatically be replaced in your current line by its content.
$ echo hello world

Alternatively, you could use replace your command line with the output of the previous command by writing $(!!) and then clicking the sequence. For instance:
$ grep ps .snippets
ps -fp $$
$ $(!!)

Clicking ALT+CTRL+e at the point, will replace the command line with the output of your grep command.
$ ps -fp $$


This is very clever, I like it. You still need a script to find your intended text first, save it in COMMAND and finally type $COMMAND and the key combo. OP seems to want to simply click on the intended text line and and see it appear on the command line.
